# how to print my cursor data values instead to insert in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following sql server cursor code to insert data.

```
Create table #tmp
(
    Ref_Code UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    Create_UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
--simple cursor in sql server 
Declare @Ref_Code UNIQUEIDENTIFIER , @Create_UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
-- declare a cursor
DECLARE insert_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Ref_Code,Create_UserId from Account_APInvoiceDetail
WHERE Ref_Code = '355199F6-0DE1-44AF-A8B2-2B1592980688';

-- open cursor and fetch first row into variables
OPEN insert_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into @Ref_Code,@Create_UserId

-- check for a new row
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
-- do complex operation here
Insert into #tmp
SELECT @Ref_Code,@Create_UserId
-- get next available row into variables
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into @Ref_Code,@Create_UserId
END
close insert_cursor
Deallocate insert_cursor
GO
```

but now i need print this data in my console as well. how can i do this?
Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `PRINT`?

Comment: actually I could not know how to print this insert data here....

Comment: [PRINT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: `PRINT N'Ref_Code:'+@Ref_Code+N'   Create_UserId:'+@Create_UserId+char(13) + char(10)`

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper where should I put this code segments...

Comment: In `while` loop may be you have to place after `Insert into #tmp
SELECT @Ref_Code,@Create_UserId`

Comment: You can also just comment out the insert statement so that only the select statement will be executed and you will see the results without inserting them.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor at all? This entire piece of code can be reduced to a single insert statement.